# Implementing an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have to write a small program to implement the following algorithm:

> Assume you have a search algorithm which, at each level of recursion, excludes half of the data from consideration when searching for a specific data item. Search stops only when one data item is left. How many levels of recursion are required when the number of elements in the data is 1024?

Do anybody has idea about how to analyze or any suggestion on how to start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the minimal value of `d` such that:

```
1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * .... * 2    = 1024
    ____________________
    total of d times
```

The above is true, because each multiplication by 2 is actually one level up in the recursion, you go up from the stop clause of 1 element, until you get the initial data size, which is 1024.

The above equation is actually `2^d = 1024`

And it is solved easily with extracting log_2 from both sides:

```
log_2(2^d) = log^2(1024)
d = 10
```

P.S. Note that the above is the number of recursive calls, exclusive of the initial call, so total number of calls to the method is `d+1=11`, one from the calling environment, and 10 from the method itself.

Comment: Dear downvoter, did you find the answer not useful? Care to elaborate so I can learn from my mistakes?

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. I will accept this answer.